FastAPI - Using exception handler in middleware throws Internal Server Error
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Query, Body, Request, HTTPException, status, Path
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from typing import Annotated


class MyCustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message="Default custom exception handler message"):
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


app = FastAPI(description="Checking my fastapi middleware")


@app.exception_handler(MyCustomException)
async def custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: MyCustomException):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, content={"message": str(exc)})


@app.middleware("http")
async def header_check(request: Request, call_next):
    auth_header = request.headers.get("x-Auth")
    if auth_header != "anilpatro":
        raise MyCustomException(message="Authentication failure")
    response = await call_next(request)
    response.headers["x-auth"] = "validated"
    return response


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str = Field(description="User name", max_length=10)
    sur_name: str | None = Field(description="Optional surname field")
    salary: int = Field(default=100, lt=10000)


class User(UserBase):
    password: str = Field(description="User password field", max_length=10)


@app.post("/usr/{user_id}")
async def get_user(user: Annotated[User, Body()],
                   user_id: Annotated[int, Path(description="user id field", gt=0)],
                   q: Annotated[int, Query(default=1)]):
    response = {"user": user.dict(), "user_id": user_id}
    if q:
        response.update({"q": q})
    return response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

In the above code the proper curl - curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:8000/usr/1?q=5" -H "x-Auth: anilpatro" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "John", "sur_name": "Doe", "salary": 900, "password": "secret"}'
is working fine, how ever for testing purpose - curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:8000/usr/1?q=5" -H "x-Auth: wrongheader" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "John", "sur_name": "Doe", "salary": 900, "password": "secret"}'
I am expecting an unauthorised exception. Am I making any mistake while calling exception handler in middleware or fastapi does not support that ?
Appreciate the support :)
In the above code the proper curl - curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:8000/usr/1?q=5" -H "x-Auth: anilpatro" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "John", "sur_name": "Doe", "salary": 900, "password": "secret"}'
is working fine, how ever for testing purpose - curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:8000/usr/1?q=5" -H "x-Auth: wrongheader" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "John", "sur_name": "Doe", "salary": 900, "password": "secret"}'
I am expecting an unauthorised exception. Am I ma`

Related answers could also be found here and here
